# Google Chrome DevTools - как держать открытым по умолчанию

Tags: google-chrome

Здравствуйте
Подскажите пожалуйста как всегда держать открытым Google Chrome DevTool с определенными настройками. Нужно эмулировать window orientation и все получается но только в текущем окне. Если выскакивает поп ап или переходим на другую страницу - открывается все без DevTools настроек, соответственно получаем не корректный результат

Answer (score 1):

Откройте Develepor Tools в отдельном окне, тогда он не будет закрываться:
Зайдите в меню (в Develepor Tools с права в верху 3 вертикальные точки) и в Dock Side Выберите Undock...